# Vaadin 7 widgetset compilation fails with "Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' "

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have an existing Vaadin 7 project that used to work ok. Now that I'm trying to compile it, the widgetset compilation fails with
`[ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly`
What could be the cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compilation error is caused by a too new JDK version. Vaadin 7 widgetset compilation only supports Java versions up to 8, and for example, IntelliJ Idea nowadays defaults to JDK 11. Switching back to JDK 8 fixes the issue.